# How can I prove formally that the projective plane is a Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want to prove the Hausdorff property of the projective space with this definition: the sphere $S^n$ with the antipodal points identified. It's seems easy, but I can't prove formally with this definition. I take neighborhoods of the points $p$, $q$ in $S^n/\sim $, with $p\neq q$. In $S^n$ we will have four points $p$, $q$, $-p$, $-q$, with 4 disjoints neighborhoods by the Hausdorff property of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. I don't know how to prove with rigour why when we pass to the quotient we will have two disjoints neighborhoods of $p$ and $q$.

Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Let $q:S^n\to P^n$ be the quotient map, and let $u,v\in P^n$ with $u\ne v$; there are $x,y\in S^n$ such that $q^{-1}[\{u\}]=\{x,-x\}$ and $q^{-1}[\{v\}]=\{y,-y\}$. Let $\epsilon=\frac13\min\{\|x-y\|,\|x+y\|\}$, and set

$$U=B(x,\epsilon)\cap S^n\quad\text{and}\quad V=B(y,\epsilon)\cap S^n\;,$$

where the open balls are taken in $\Bbb R^n$. Then $U,V,-U$, and $-V$ are pairwise disjoint open nbhds of $x,y,-x$, and $-y$, respectively, in $S^n$. Moreover, $q^{-1}\big[q[U]\big]=-U\cup U$ and $q^{-1}\big[q[V]\big]=-V\cup V$. Show that $q[U]$ and $q[V]$ are disjoint open nbhds of $u$ and $v$ in $P^n$.

Comment: Why did you take such a $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Rafael: It was convenient. I could have used any $\epsilon\le\frac12\min\{\|x-y\|,\|x+y\|\}$.

Comment: yes, of course, thank you :)

Comment: @Rafael: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If we take the "lines through $0$ and $x$" definition of $\mathbb P^n$, does it work equivalently to minimize the distance of $y$ over some right compact subset of the line through $0$ and $x$?

Comment: @Anthony: I don’t understand what you’re asking, I’m afraid.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott My question is: to prove $\mathbb P^n$ is Hausdorff using the 'line through the origin formulation', is it proper to take the minimum distance from $x$ to the line through $y$ and take half of this as the radius $\epsilon$? Indeed it seems the same idea as what you've done, but you've done it with only two points on the line $L_y$, $y,-y$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In particular, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699700/real-projective-space-mathbb-pn-is-hausdorff?noredirect=1#comment3469057_1699700

Comment: @Anthony: If I understand correctly what you’re doing, it won’t necessarily work. Suppose that $\|x\|$ is much larger than $\|y\|$, and we use your $\epsilon$: a ball of that radius around $y$ may well contain a segment of $L_x$. When $\|x\|\ne\|y\|$, the situation is no longer symmetric.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What if we take half the minimum of the distance from $x$ to $L_y$ and $y$ to $L_x$?

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, that should work. My own inclination would be simply to normalize $x$ and $y$, at which point you have essentially the situation with which I was working here, but that is perhaps a matter of taste.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah I see. Thanks for your help as always!

Comment: @Anthony: My pleasure!

Answer (score 24):

Let $G$ be a compact Hausdorff group.
Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Suppose $G$ acts continuously on $X$.
We will prove that the orbit space $X/G$ is Hausdorff.
The proof is due to Bourbaki.
As an immediate corollary, projective spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are Hausdorff.

**Definition 1**
Let $X, Y$ be locally compact Haudsorff spaces.
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map.
If $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact for every compact subset $K$ of $Y$, $f$ is called a proper map.

**Lemma 1**
Let $X$ be a topological space.
Let $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of subsets of $X$.
Suppose $X = \bigcup_i int(A_i)$, where $int(A_i)$ is the interior of $A_i$.
Let $B$ be a subset of $X$.
Suppose $B \cap A_i$ is closed in $A_i$ for every $i \in I$.
Then $B$ is closed in $X$.

Proof:
Let $C = X - B$.
Since $C \cap A_i = A_i - (B \cap A_i)$, $C \cap A_i$ is open in $A_i$.
Hence there exists an open subset $V_i$ of $X$ such that $C \cap A_i = V_i \cap A_i$.
Then $C \cap int(A_i) = (C \cap A_i) \cap int(A_i) = (V_i \cap A_i) \cap int(A_i)
= V_i \cap int(A_i)$.
Hence $C \cap int(A_i)$ is open in $X$.
Since $X = \bigcup int(A_i)$, $C = \bigcup (C \cap int(A_i))$.
Hence $C$ is open in $X$.
Hence $B$ is closed in $X$.
**QED**

**Lemma 2**
Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces.
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a continuous map.
Let $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of subsets of $Y$.
Suppose $Y = \bigcup_i int(A_i)$.
Let $f_i\colon f^{-1}(A_i) \rightarrow A_i$ be the restriction of $f$ for each $i \in I$.
Suppose $f_i$ is a closed map for every $i \in I$.
Then $f$ is a closed map.

Proof:
Let $B$ be a closed subset of $X$.
Since $f(B) \cap A_i = f_i(B \cap f^{-1}(A_i))$, $f(B) \cap A_i$ is closed in $A_i$ for every $i \in I$.
Hence $f$ is a closed map by Lemma 1.
**QED**

**Lemma 3**
Let $X, Y$ be locally compact Hausdorff spaces.
Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper map.
Then $f$ is a closed map.

Proof:
There exists a family $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ of compact subsets of $Y$ such that $Y = \bigcup_i int(A_i)$.Let $f_i\colon f^{-1}(A_i) \rightarrow A_i$ be the restriction of $f$ for each $i \in I$.
Since $f$ is proper, $f^{-1}(A_i)$ is compact.
Hence $f_i$ is a closed map.
Hence $f$ is a closed map by Lemma 2.
**QED**

**Definition 2**
Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group.
Let $X$ a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Suppose $G$ acts on $X$ continuously.
Suppose the map $f\colon G\times X \rightarrow X\times X$ defined by $f(s, x) = (x, sx)$ is proper.
Then we say $G$ acts properly on $X$.

**Definition 3**
Suppose a group $G$ acts on a set $X$.
Let $K, L$ be subsets of $X$.
We denote $P(K, L) = \{s \in G| sK \cap L \neq \emptyset\}$.

**Lemma 4**
Let $X, Y$ be Hausdorff spaces.
Let $C$ be a compact subset of $X\times Y$.
Then there exists a compact subset $K$(resp. $L$) of $X$(resp. $L$) such that $C \subset K\times L$.

Proof:
Let $K$(resp. $L$) be the image of $C$ by the projection map on the first(resp. the second) factor of $X\times X$.
Then $K$ and $L$ are compact and $C \subset K\times L$.
**QED**

**Lemma 5**
Let $f\colon X_1 \rightarrow Y_1$(resp. $g\colon X_2 \rightarrow Y_2$) be a proper map.
Then $f\times g\colon X_1\times X_2 \rightarrow Y_1 \times Y_2$ is proper.

Proof:
Let $C$ be a compact subset of $Y_1\times Y_2$.
By Lemma 4, there exists a compact subset $K$(resp. $L$) of $Y_1$(resp. $Y_2$) such that $C \subset K\times L$.
Since $(f\times g)^{-1}(K\times L) = f^{-1}(K)\times g^{-1}(L)$ is compact, $(f\times g)^{-1}(C)$ is compact.
**QED**

**Lemma 6**
Let $X$ be a compact Haudsorff space.
Let $Y$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Then the projection map $\pi\colon X\times Y \rightarrow Y$ is proper.

Proof:
Let $p$ be a one point space.
Then $f\colon X \rightarrow p$ is proper.
Hence, by Lemma 5, $\pi = f\times id_Y\colon X \times Y \rightarrow p\times Y = Y$ is proper.
**QED**

**Lemma 7**
Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group.
Let $X$ a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Suppose $G$ acts on $X$ continuously.
Then $P(K, L)$ is closed for any compact subsets $K, L$ of $X$.

Proof:
Let $f\colon G\times X \rightarrow X$ be the map defined by $f(s, x) = sx$.
Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(L)$ is closed.
Let $\pi\colon G\times K \rightarrow G$ be the projection.
By Lemma 6, $\pi$ is proper.
Hence, by Lemma 3, $\pi$ is a closed map.
Hence $P(K, L) = \pi(f^{-1}(L))$ is closed.
**QED**

**Lemma 8**
Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group.
Let $X$ a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Suppose $G$ acts on $X$ continuously.
Suppose $P(K, L)$ is compact for any compact subsets $K, L$ of $X$.
Then $G$ acts properly on $X$.

Proof:
Let $h\colon G\times X \rightarrow X\times X$ be the map defined by $h(s, x) = (x, sx)$.
Let $C$ be a compact subset of $X\times X$.
By Lemma 4, there exist compact subsets $K, L$ of $X$ such that $C \subset K\times L$.
Then $h^{-1}(K\times L) \subset P(K, L)\times K$.
Since $P(K, L)\times K$ is compact and $h^{-1}(K\times L)$ is closed, $h^{-1}(K\times L)$ is compact.
Since $C \subset K\times L$, $h^{-1}(C) \subset h^{-1}(K\times L)$.
Since $h^{-1}(C)$ is closed, it is compact.
Hence $h$ is proper.
Hence $G$ acts proplerly on $X$.
**QED**

**Lemma 9**
Let $X$ be a topological space.
Let $R$ be an equivalence relation on $X$.
Let $X/R$ be the quotient space.
Let $\pi\colon X \rightarrow X/R$ be the canonical map.
Let $\Gamma = \{(x, y)\in X\times X| x \equiv y$ (mod $R)\}$.
Suppose $\pi$ is an open map and $\Gamma$ is closed.
Then $X/R$ is Hausdorff.

Proof:
Let $\rho := \pi\times \pi\colon X\times X \rightarrow (X/R)\times (X/R)$.
Since $\pi$ is an open map, so is $\rho$.
Since $\rho(\Gamma)$ is the diagonal subset of $(X/R)\times (X/R)$, it suffices to prove that $\rho(\Gamma)$ is closed.
Since $\Gamma = \rho^{-1}(\rho(\Gamma)$, $X\times X - \Gamma = \rho^{-1}((X/R)\times (X/R) - \rho(\Gamma))$.
Since $\rho$ is surjective, $\rho(X\times X - \Gamma) = (X/R)\times (X/R) - \rho(\Gamma)$.
Since $\rho$ is an open map and $X\times X - \Gamma$ is open, $(X/R)\times (X/R) - \rho(\Gamma)$ is open.
Hence $\rho(\Gamma)$ is closed.
**QED**

**Lemma 10**
Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group.
Let $X$ a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Suppose $G$ acts properly on $X$.
Then the orbit space $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

Proof:
Let $\pi\colon X \rightarrow X/G$ be the canonical map.
Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$.
Then $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) = GU$.
Since $GU$ is open, $\pi$ is an open map.
By Lemma 9, it suffices to prove that $\Gamma = \{(x, y) \in X\times X| x \equiv y$ (mod $G)\}$ is closed.
Let $h\colon G\times X \rightarrow X\times X$ be the map defined by $h(s, x) = (x, sx)$.
Since $G$ acts properly on $X$, $h$ is proper.
Hence $h$ is closed by Lemma 3.
Hence $\Gamma = h(G\times X)$ is closed.
**QED**

**Proposition**
Let $G$ be a compact Hausdorff group.
Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Suppose $G$ acts continuously on $X$.
Then $G$ acts properly on $X$.
Hence the orbit space $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

Proof:
By Lemma 7, $P(K, L)$ is closed for any compact subsets $K, L$ of $X$.
Since $G$ is compact, $P(K, L)$ is compact.
Hence, by Lemma 8, $G$ acts proplerly on $X$.
Hence, by Lemma 10, $X/G$ is Hausdorff.
**QED**

**Corollary**
Let $K$ be the field of real numbers or the field of complex numbers.
Then the projective space $P^n(K)$ over $K$ is Hausdorff.

Proof:
Let $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in K^n$.
We denote $||x|| = (\sum_i x_i \bar x_i)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.
Let $G = \{x \in K|\ |x| = 1\}$.
Then $G$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of $K$.
Let $X = \{x \in K^n|\ ||x|| = 1\}$.
Clearly $G$ acts on $X$ continuously.
Since $G$ and $X$ are compact Hausdorff spaces, $X/G$ is Hausdorff by the proposition.
Since $P^n(K) = X/G$, the assertion follows.
**QED**

**Remark 1**
The above proposition holds without assuming $X$ is locally Hausdorff, but only assuming it is Hausdorff as the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242442/is-the-orbit-space-of-a-hausdorff-space-by-a-compact-hausdorff-group-hausdorff) shows.

**Remark 2**
If $G$ and $X$ are both compact Hausdorff, it is easy to prove that $X/G$ is Hausdorff.
Let $\Gamma = \{(x, y) \in X\times X| x \equiv y$ (mod $G)\}$.
Let $h\colon G\times X \rightarrow X\times X$ be the map defined by $h(s, x) = (x, sx)$.
Since $h$ is continuous, $\Gamma = h(G\times X)$ is compact, hence closed.
By Lemma 9, $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: The theory of proper actions is essentially due to Palais, *[On the existence of slices for actions of non-compact Lie groups](http://vmm.math.uci.edu/ExistenceOfSlices.pdf)*. Another nice exposition is in Koszul's TIFR *[Lectures on Groups of transformations](http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~publ/ln/tifr32.pdf)*.

Comment: @commenter Thanks for the nice links.

Comment: Great answer, I was interested in the same and found this using google. Thanks Makoto Kato!!!

Comment: @FabianWerner You're welcome. :)

Comment: In the corollary, what do you mean by $|x|=1$ in the definition of $G$, is that norm?

Comment: @MakotoKato can you maybe put this edit in: https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/813430
it was rejected rather arbitrarily... (I supposedly changed the intent of your proof when I didn't - all I did was fill a small gap).

Answer (score 8):

You did ask explicitly for a proof that uses the construction of projective space as a quotient of $S^n$, but consider this for fun. If you are willing to consider the projective space as the set of lines through $0$ in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, then there is an intuative geometric way of seeing the Hausdorff property, that one should be able to convert into a rigorous proof:

Let $x$ and $y$ be distinct points in $\mathbb P^n$. Let $l_x$ and $l_y$ be the corresponding lines in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. The Hausdorff property of projective space follows from the fact that we can fit the lines into two cones in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ that only have $0$ in common, whose projections to projective space then give disjoint open sets that contain $x$ and $y$. It's helpful to draw a picture of the 2-dimensional situation to get a feel for this; to construct the cones you can fix an inner product and take the set of lines whose angle with $l_x$ (resp. $l_y$) is less than some $\epsilon > 0$. (By doing this we're basically making $\mathbb P^n$ into a metric space, whence the Hausdorff property follows.)

Comment: Why cones? the neighborhood of the points of $\mathbb P^n$ in this case are cones? thanks for your answer

Comment: I picked cones for ease of use, but you can use whatever disjoint open sets that contain each line you want. The idea is just to get open sets on $\mathbb P^n$ by building them "upstairs" in the quotient topology. It really helps to draw a picture in $\mathbb R^2$ to see what's going on!

Answer (score 7):

Recall that an equivalence relation $\sim$ on a topological space X is said to be $\textit{open}$ if for every open subset $A$ of $X$, the set $$[A] := \{x \in X | x \sim a \text{ for some a} \in A\}$$ is also open. It is easy to see that group actions on topological spaces give open equivalence relations. It is not hard to show the following

$\textbf{Lemma. }$ Let $\sim$ be an open equivalence relation on a space $X$. Then $X /\sim$ is Hausdorff iff the set $\{(x,y)| x \sim y\}$ is closed in $X \times X$.

Let $X = \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - 0$ and $\sim$ be the quotient by the action of $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ by scaling. Define a real valued function $f$ on $X \times X$ as 
$$f(x_1, ..., x_{n+1}, y_1,...,y_{n+1}) = \sum_{i \neq j}(x_i y_j - y_i x_j)^2 . $$Then $f(x,y)$ is clearly continuous and vanishes iff $y = \lambda x$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, that is, iff $x \sim y.$ Thus we have that $$f^{-1}(0) = \{(x,y)| x \sim y\} $$ is closed in $X \times X$ and by the lemma, $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Instead of  R^+ positive reals under usual multiplication, it should be R* nonzero reals with under usual multiplication

Answer (score 5):

Another way to see this is to note that $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is a CW-complex with one cell in each dimension $i\leq n$ i.e

$$\mathbb{R}P^n=\bigcup_{i=0} ^n e^n.$$

Since CW-complexes are Hausdorff, $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is.

Comment: where can I see this definition of $\mathbb RP^n$? thanks for your answer

Comment: @rafaelchavez on page 6 of: http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf

Comment: +1 for pointing out this wonderful construction! This is the shortest and (in my opinion) the most elegant proof of the Hausdorff-ness of $\Bbb RP^n$.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the nicest approach to prove that $\Bbb{R}P^n$ is Hausdorff is to notice that it is the orbit space $S^n/(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})$ where the action of $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ is given by the antipodal map. The following problem (which you should try to do) will now complete the proof that real projective space is Hausdorff:

> > Let $G$ be a finite group that acts on a Hausdorff space $X$. Then the orbit space $X/G$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be the field of real numbers or the field of complex numbers.
Let $G = K^*$ be the multiplicative group of $K$.
Let $X = K^{n+1} - {0}$.
Then $G$ acts on $X$.
We regard $X$ as a topological subspace of $K^{n+1}$.
Then the projective space $P^n$ over $K$ is, by defintion, the orbit space $X/G$ with the quotient topology.

Let $\pi\colon X \rightarrow P^n$ be the canonical map.
Let $x = (x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n) \in X$.
We denote $\pi(x)$ by $[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n]$.
Let $\Delta = \{(x,x) \in P^n\times P^n| x \in P^n\}$.
To prove that $P^n$ is Hausdorff, it suffices to prove that $\Delta$ is closed in $P^n\times P^n$.

Let $([x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n], [y_0,y_1,\dots,y_n]) \in \Delta$.
Suppose $x_i \neq 0$.
Then $y_i \neq 0$ and $x_j/x_i = y_j/y_i$ for $i \neq j$.
Hence $x_iy_j = x_jy_i$ for $i \neq j, 0\le i, j\le n$.

Conversely suppose $([x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n], [y_0,y_1,\dots,y_n]) \in P^n\times P^n$.
Suppose $x_iy_j = x_jy_i$ for $i \neq j, 0\le i, j\le n$.
Suppose $x_i \neq 0$. If $y_i = 0$, then $y_j = 0$ for all $j$.
This is a contradiction.
Hence $y_i \neq 0$.
Hence $x_j/x_i = y_j/y_i$ for all $j \neq i$.
Hence $([x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n], [y_0,y_1,\dots,y_n]) \in \Delta$.

Therefore $\Delta = \{([x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n], [y_0,y_1,\dots,y_n]) \in P^n\times P^n| x_iy_j = x_jy_i, i\neq j, 0\le i,j\le n\}$.
Let $U_i = \{[x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n] \in P^n|\ x_i \neq 0\}$.
Then $U_i$ is an open subset of $P^n$ and it is is canonically isomorphic to $K^n$(see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210265/how-do-i-prove-that-mathbb-cpn-is-a-2n-manifold)).
Clearly $(U_i)_{i \in I}$ is an open cover of $P^n$, where $I = \{0,1,\dots,n\}$.
Hence $(U_i\times U_j)_{(i, j) \in I\times I}$ is an open cover of $P^n\times P^n$.
Since $\Delta$ is the common zeros of bihomogeneous polynomials $x_iy_j - x_jy_i, i\neq j$,
$(U_i\times U_j) \cap \Delta$ is canonically isomorphic to an algebraic subset of $K^n\times K^n$(e.g. see Mychael Joyce's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242312/proof-that-the-common-zeros-of-multihomogeneous-polynomials-is-a-zariski-closed)).
Hence it is closed in $U_i\times U_j$.
Hence $\Delta$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

The proof I'll give bellow works for the fields $\mathbb K = \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$. It also works for $\mathbb  K = \mathbb H$. Let $S$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb K^{n+1}$ and $S_{\mathbb K}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb K$, i.e.,
$$ S_{\mathbb R} = \{-1, 1\}\quad \text{and}\quad \quad S_{\mathbb C} = \mathbb S^1.$$

We have the surjective map $\pi:S \to \mathbb P_{\mathbb K}^n$ given by $\pi(x) = [x]$. The topology considered in the projective space is the quotient topology. Notice that if $U \subset S$ is open, then 
$$\pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) = \cup_{\gamma\in S_{\mathbb K}} \gamma U$$
is open
and therefore $\pi$ is an open map.

Now, take $[x],[y] \in \mathbb P_{\mathbb K}^n$, $[x] \neq [y]$. Notice $$\pi^{-1}[x] = \{\gamma x \in S:\gamma \in S_{\mathbb K}\} = S_{\mathbb K} x.$$

The map $S_{\mathbb K} \to \pi^{-1}[x]$ given by $\gamma \mapsto \gamma x$ is homeomorphism and therefore $\pi^{-1}[x]$ is compact. So, we have $\pi^{-1}[x]$ and $\pi^{-1}[y]$ are closed subsets of $S$. Clearly they are also disjoint.

By the Urysohn's lemma, there is a continuous function $g:S \to \mathbb R$ such that $g|_{\pi^{-1}[x]} = 1$ and $g|_{\pi^{-1}[y]} = 0$.

But this function is not necessarly invariant under action of $S_{\mathbb K}$, so we define $h: S \to \mathbb R$ by the formula
$$h(x) = \int_{S_{\mathbb K}} g(\gamma x) d\gamma,$$
where $d\gamma$ is the Haar measure of $S_{\mathbb K}$. More explicitly,
$$h(x) = \frac{1}{2}(g(x)+g(-x))\quad \text{for} \quad \mathbb K = \mathbb R$$
and
$$h(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} g(e^{i\theta}x)d\theta\quad \text{for} \quad \mathbb K = \mathbb C.$$

Now, since the sets $\pi^{-1}[x]$ and $\pi^{-1}[y]$ are invariant under action of $S_{\mathbb K}$, we have $h|_{\pi^{-1}[x]} = 1$ and $h|_{\pi^{-1}[y]} = 0$.

This function $h$ is a function on the projective space. More precisely, define $\widehat h: \mathbb P_{\mathbb K}^n \to \mathbb R$ by the formula $\widehat h([z]) = h(z)$. Since, $h(\gamma z) = h(z)$ for $\gamma \in S_{\mathbb K}$, the function $\widehat h$ is well defined. Besides that, since $h = \widehat h \circ \pi$ and $\pi$ is open map, we obtain $\widehat h$ is continuous.

Taking the open sets $U = \widehat h^{-1}(1/2,\infty)$ and $V = \widehat h^{-1}(-\infty,1/2)$ we have $[x] \in U$, $[y] \in V$ and $U \cap V = \varnothing$, proving $\mathbb P_{\mathbb K}^n$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, and in may others, it is way easier to use the following equaivalent definition of Hasudorff:

**Definition:** A topological space X is Hausdorff iff the Diagonal $\,\Delta_X:=\{(x,x)\in X^2\}\,$ is closed in the product space $\,X\times X\,$

Comment: How does this help here?

Comment: @WillG Decisively...but I can hardly remember that.