# Hausdorffness of quotient space

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

Let $G$ be a compact topological group, and $X$ be a Hausdorff space. We assume that $G$ acts on $X$.  Is the quotient space $X/G$ with the quotient topology a Hausdorff space?  It seems that the answer is YES from this post [How can I prove formally that the projective plane is a Hausdorff space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241711/how-can-i-prove-formally-that-the-projective-plane-is-a-hausdorff-space) , if we assume further that $X$ is  locally compact.  My question is whether this  locally compactness condition can be removed.